# Font scaling based on width of container with js libs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, font-size, fittextjs

I'm trying to implement font-size scaling based on width of container (I want my long `h1` to be in one line).

Here is my HTML with bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="responsive-headline">LONG TEXT IS
                LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG</h1>
                <ul class="breadcrumbs">
                    ...
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS styles:

```
.responsive-headline {
    margin: 0px 0px 3px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
    letter-spacing: 1.7px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

Ok. Let's start from [FitText.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js) library:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.responsive-headline').fitText();
});
```

Result `font-size: 114px;`! What?
Add some parameters:

```
$('h1.responsive-headline').fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: '18px',
maxFontSize: '32px' });
```

Result `font-size: 32px;`. Better but not what I want, I need smaller font-size. Also tried to add `width: 1000px; display: block; white-space: nowrap;` to `h1` without success.

Second library that I tried is [FlowType.js](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/). Add some code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('h1.responsive-headline').flowtype();
});
```

Result `font-size: 32.5714px;`. Little bigger than default.
And with parameters:

```
$('h1.responsive-headline').flowtype({
    minFont   : 12,
    maxFont   : 32
});
```

Result `font-size: 32px;`.

Why my `h1` becomes bigger but not smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Might it be because you are calculating the font-size on (document).ready?
If you're looking for a more dynamic sizing "responsive", maybe try the resize() method?
https://api.jquery.com/resize/

My appologies if im misunderstanding.

Comment: Same result when I put my js code outside the `(document).ready` code block.